# Why is my makefile not making one of the targets?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm required to submit my program along with a makefile for an assignment but for some reason it is not making the target `helper.o` even though the command for that step (`gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c helper.c`) works when I type it into the command line manually. When I type the make command I get this error:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c createTweet.c
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c displayTweets.c
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c searchTweetsByKeyword.c
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c countStopWords.c
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c deleteTweet.c
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c saveTweetsToFile.c
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c loadTweetsFromFile.c
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c sortID.c
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c addNodeToList.c
cc    -c -o mainA3.o mainA3.c
gcc -Wall -std=c99 createTweet.o displayTweets.o searchTweetsByKeyword.o countStopWords.o deleteTweet.o saveTweetsToFile.o loadTweetsFromFile.o sortID.o addNodeToList.o helper.o mainA3.o -o matiwosEyoelA3
gcc: error: helper.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [makefile:2: outputA3] Error 1 '''
```

Here: is my makefile:

```
outputA3: createTweet.o displayTweets.o searchTweetsByKeyword.o countStopWords.o deleteTweet.o saveTweetsToFile.o loadTweetsFromFile.o sortID.o addNodeToList.o mainA3.o
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 createTweet.o displayTweets.o searchTweetsByKeyword.o countStopWords.o deleteTweet.o saveTweetsToFile.o loadTweetsFromFile.o sortID.o addNodeToList.o helper.o mainA3.o -o outputA3
helper.o: helper.h headerA3.h helper.c
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c helper.c
createTweet.o: createTweet.c helper.h headerA3.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c createTweet.c
displayTweets.o: displayTweets.c helper.h headerA3.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c displayTweets.c
searchTweetsByKeyword.o: searchTweetsByKeyword.c helper.h headerA3.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c searchTweetsByKeyword.c
countStopWords.o: countStopWords.c helper.h headerA3.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c countStopWords.c
deleteTweet.o: deleteTweet.c helper.h headerA3.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c deleteTweet.c
saveTweetsToFile.o: saveTweetsToFile.c helper.h headerA3.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c saveTweetsToFile.c
loadTweetsFromFile.o: loadTweetsFromFile.c helper.h headerA3.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c loadTweetsFromFile.c
sortID.o: sortID.c helper.h headerA3.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c sortID.c
addNodeToList.o: addNodeToList.c helper.h headerA3.h
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c addNodeToList.c
clean: 
    rm *.o outputA3
```

Why might this be happening?

Comment: What happens if you change `helper.o: helper.h headerA3.h helper.c` to `helper.o: helper.c headerA3.h helper.h`? List the .c file first.

Comment: Looks like `helper.o` is not in your dependency list for `outputA3`

Comment: @Accumulator It seems like I get the same result

Comment: @ChristianGibbons thank you, that seems to have been the problem. I figured it was something simple but it was due in a couple of hours so I started panicking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `matiwosEyoelA3: ...` does not list `helper.o` as a dependency.

That's a problem because you repeat so many file names and violate the "don't write it twice" rule. Use variables and make's builtin variables like $^.

e.g.

```
OBJECTS = createTweet.o displayTweets.o searchTweetsByKeyword.o \
          countStopWords.o deleteTweet.o saveTweetsToFile.o \
          loadTweetsFromFile.o sortID.o addNodeToList.o \
          mainA3.o helper.o
outputA3: $(OBJECTS)
      gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o $@ $^
```

Comment: kudos for breaking this  overlong line

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks. I hate scrollbars, vertical, horizontal, diagonal, ... :-)

Comment: How about [Cinnamon Scroll Bars](https://bluedinosaur.com.au/products/cinnamon-scroll-bar)?

Answer (score 2):

Your target `outputA3:` does not depend on `helper.o`.

Change the first line to -

```
outputA3: createTweet.o displayTweets.o searchTweetsByKeyword.o countStopWords.o deleteTweet.o saveTweetsToFile.o loadTweetsFromFile.o sortID.o addNodeToList.o mainA3.o helper.o
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 createTweet.o displayTweets.o searchTweetsByKeyword.o countStopWords.o deleteTweet.o saveTweetsToFile.o loadTweetsFromFile.o sortID.o addNodeToList.o helper.o mainA3.o -o outputA3
```

(notice the extra `helper.o` at the end)

One way to avoid such issues in the future is to use `$^` to refer to all the dependencies instead of listing them.

So you can change the target to -

```
outputA3: createTweet.o displayTweets.o searchTweetsByKeyword.o countStopWords.o deleteTweet.o saveTweetsToFile.o loadTweetsFromFile.o sortID.o addNodeToList.o mainA3.o helper.o
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 $^ -o $@
```

This way you don't have to write the dependencies again and if you miss something you get a linker error telling you which file is missing.

Answer (score 0):

`helper.o` is not in the list of dependencies for `outputA3` target, while it is in the linking list of requisites.  This makes `make` not to compile it, but the linker blames at you because it is not found.

A good idea can be to create a `make` variable with the set of objects of `outputA3`, as in:

```
outputA3_objs = createTweet.o displayTweets.o searchTweetsByKeyword.o countStopWords.o deleteTweet.o saveTweetsToFile.o loadTweetsFromFile.o sortID.o addNodeToList.o helper.o mainA3.o
outputA3: $(outputA3_objs)
    gcc -Wall -std=c99 $(outputA3_objs) -o $@
```

and this way, if you need to change the list, you have to do it in only one place, making your `Makefile` more robust to changes.

Answer (score 0):

make is much more powerful than what you apparently think. Thanks to the other answers you fixed your Makefile. Here is a bit simpler and less error prone Makefile (for GNU make):

```
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -std=c99

outputA3: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c helper.h headerA3.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) outputA3
```

This assumes that the executable is `outputA3` (as in your own Makefile) and not `matiwosEyoelA3` (as in the error messages you show), and that all C files are part of the project. Adapt if needed.

Note: GNU make already knows how to compile and link. If you accept that your executable is named `mainA3` instead of `outputA3` or `matiwosEyoelA3`, the following should also work:

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -std=c99

mainA3: $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
%.o: helper.h headerA3.h

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o mainA3
```